# Enable To Date Only after filling the From Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap datepicker and I want to know is there a way to enable To Date Only after filling the From Date.Before that it will be disable. Both javascript or jQuery solutions are welcome.

*my html*

```
<div id="div2" style="display: none">   
            <div class="row m-t-5">
            <div class="col-md-8">From Date </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="leave_from" onblur="checkDate();" name="leave_from" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-t-5">
            <div class="col-md-8">To Date </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="leave_to" onblur="checkDate();" name="leave_to" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
```

*my javascript code*

```
function checkDate(){
var error;
var $validator = $("#myform").validate();
var date1      = document.getElementById('leave_from').value;
var date       = date1.substring(0, 2);
var month      = date1.substring(3, 5);
var year       = date1.substring(6, 10);
var FROM       = new Date(year, month - 1, date);

var date2       = document.getElementById('leave_to').value;
var date1       = date2.substring(0, 2);
var month1      = date2.substring(3, 5);
var year1       = date2.substring(6, 10);
var TO          = new Date(year1, month1 - 1, date1);

if(FROM > TO)
{
error = {leave_to:"Invalid Date!"};
$validator.showErrors(error);
$('#leave_to').val('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add your html and javascript

Comment: @KiranShahi: updated my post

Comment: what do you mean by "feeling" the form?

Comment: @Taulant: it's From Date not form. there is a difference.

Comment: and guys please have the courtesy to explain before downvoting.

Comment: I see the difference, my bad. Nevertheless i still do not understand what you mean by "feeling" which was my point in that cmt.

Comment: @Taulant: it was a typo. corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,


autoclose: true
  }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
   $('#datepicker2').prop('disabled',false);
});
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,

autoclose: true
  });
$('#datepicker2').prop('disabled',true);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="panel">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker1">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker2">Date2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hoe this will help you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this version of the code. Make sure that the first date must be set before heading to the second one. If someone is setting the first date, then the second and then delete the first, the second will also be cleared and disabled again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,


autoclose: true
  }).on("change", function (e) {
   if($('#datepicker1').val() == ""){
     $('#datepicker2').prop('disabled',true);
   }else{
     $('#datepicker2').val('');
     $('#datepicker2').prop('disabled',false);
   }
});
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,

autoclose: true
  });
$('#datepicker2').prop('disabled',true);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="panel">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker1">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker2">Date2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```